# procedure execution in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I want to execute a procedure inside another procedure, which includes a cursor definition,by inserting this line:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SAP_IMP_IE_FGZ_INSCRI_RULES (V_START_DATE IN DATE 
DEFAULT SYSDATE, v_count_max IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1000) AS

EXECUTE procedure SAP_IMP_FGZ_INSCRI_DBL;

CURSOR c_CURSEUR IS
SELECT
..
```

but it displays for me the following error .
Note that the procedure includes a cursor definition

```
Erreur(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting 
one of the following: begin function package pragma procedure subtype  
type use <identificateur> <identificateur entre guillemets> form  
current cursor external language
```

Comment: Inside PL/SQL, just write  `SAP_IMP_FGZ_INSCRI_DBL;`, no `execute` no `procedure` necessary. But you can't do that in the "declare" part. It has to be a statement in the body of the procedure.

Comment: I see.
but in my case, the procedure that I want to execute at the top of the global procedure defines the rules to be respected before I get my data with the cursor, thing that seems impossible in the declare part.

Comment: The cursor is only _declared_ in the declare block. It is not opened (=executed) until you actually have an `open c_curseur`

Comment: So I must execute SAP_IMP_FGZ_INSCRI_DBL just before an open c_curseur ?